# Convert JSON to CSV and print directly (Python)

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I need to convert a json object to csv and print it directly and NOT write it to a file like the pandas method does. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

you can try via `read_json()`+`to_csv()`:

```
print(pd.read_json('yourjson.json',lines=True).to_csv())
```

OR

If your json is stored in a variable then:

```
print(pd.Series(your json variable).to_csv())
```

**Note:** except `path_or_buf` parameter pass any parameter in `to_csv()` method according to your need(if needed)